# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2+(-1)^n)x^n$ radius of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How can I find the radius of convergence of the power series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2+(-1)^n)x^n \ ?$$ I know what the radius is, but how should a series of this form be handled?

Comment: $1 \le 2+(-1)^n \le 3$ and you can use comparaison

Comment: Do you know Cauchy-Hadamard theorem?

Comment: How about the root test?  the series converges when $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \left((2+(-1)^n) x^n\right)^\frac 1n  = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} \left((2+(-1)^n) \right)^\frac 1n x< 1$

Comment: I was not familiar with Cauchy-Hadamard, it seems very useful. But I think it is a bit off-limits in this exercise. I was thinking more along the lines of comparison and the root test, but I find it hard to get a clear picture of what's happening. How exactly does comparison to the upper and lower limits guarantee convergence in the same interval in a situation like this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd add a correct answer as somebody, as usual, rushed to downvote the other, incorrect, answer I gave instead of  warning and waiting...

Use Cauchy-Hadamard:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|2+(-1)^n\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]3=1$$

and thus $\;R=1\;$ .

BTW, the $\;n\,-$ th root sequence of the given series converges, no matter the original sequence doesn't...

Comment: Couldn't resist commenting on the first (quite passive-aggressive) sentence: you are complaining about someone downvoting an answer that you admit was *incorrect*? Isn't that one of the uses of downvoting? (And if the downvoting was "rushed," then what about the answer, then?)

Comment: @ClementC. Yes...and it is not the first time (you should know: we both are members many years...). Much of the animosity many times exists between different elements in this site is due to these things, and it makes no harm to remark a mistake (and mine was ugly) and wait for correction, which many times is just a typo, an omission or whatever. That's my opinion. In this case, for example, I won't undelete that question because there's a downvote, which may be deleted...or not, and it can be misleadig for following readers of the answer. Thus, what I wrote.

Comment: But then, correct your answer instead of deleting it -- hopefully, the downvoter would revert their vote in front of the new, now correct, answer. At least that's what should happen, and what cannot happen with your delete-and-replace strategy.

Comment: @ClementC.  I think that if we wait for "what should happen" in this site we can wait until eternity, and I've not that much time. The opposite of "what should happen" has happened before **many** times and in **many** different situations. I'd rather do what I did now. Anyway, no harm done.

Comment: True. In the end, no big deal.

Comment: I also think that a comment would be better than a downvote to advice about a mistake or a typo.